# Delphi: create a tree of files in TreeView depending on their names

Tags: delphi, treeview

I have a string list of files and a date as their names (separators can be different: "-|."; a mask: `yyyy/mm/dd`):

```
2011-03-12.jpeg
2011|10-15.doc
2011.08-09.rar
2011.10-15.txt
2011-03-14.jpeg
2011.06.23.mp3
2011|07|01.zip
2011-07-05.rar
```

How can I create a Tree View with them? All files must be sorted by a month and day + allocated into month-sections like:

[image]

Big thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have a `TStringList` populated, I would simply sort it using its `CustomSort()` method, and then you can loop through it adding the nodes to the tree as needed, eg:

```
function SortFilesByMonthAndDay(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
var
  Value1, Value2: Integer;
begin
  Value1 := StrToInt(Copy(List[Index1], 6, 2));
  Value2 := StrToInt(Copy(List[Index2], 6, 2));
  if Value1 = Value2 then
  begin
    Value1 := StrToInt(Copy(List[Index1], 9, 2));
    Value2 := StrToInt(Copy(List[Index2], 9, 2));
  end;
  Result := Value2 - Value1;
end;

var
  I: Integer;
  FileMonth, CurrentMonth: Integer;
  CurrentMonthNode: TTreeNode;
begin
  CurrentMonth := 0;
  CurrentMonthNode := nil;
  Files.CustomSort(@SortFilesByMonthAndDay);
  for I := 0 to Files.Count-1 do
  begin
    FileMonth := StrToInt(Copy(Files[I], 6, 2));
    if FileMonth <> CurrentMonth then
    begin
      CurrentMonth := FileMonth;
      CurrentMonthNode := TreeView1.Items.Add(nil, SysUtils.LongMonthNames[CurrentMonth]);
    end;
    TreeView1.Items.AddChild(CurrentMonthNode, Files[I]);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create an array of 12 string lists, one per month.
- Iterate through your files adding each file name to the appropriate month.
- Once all files have been processed, sort each individual string list with an appropriate sort order.
- Finally, populate the tree view. For each string list, add a top level node and then add all the children by iterating through the string list.

I'm assuming that you already know how to parse individual strings, how to implement a custom sort order, and how to populate a string list, and that your problem is how to tackle the problem from a high level.